# static files do not show on a live django site served via nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, server

I was following a digitalocean tutorial to build a site on a server with django, gunicorn & nginx. The site is live, but the static files don't show.

the syntax is clean
I concluded that the problem must be either from django or nginx (since any static files' configuration is related to either of them

I tried modifying django & nginx configuration since they the source as it seems.

1) the static location definition in the django settings.py file django_project/django_project/settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/',
STATIC_ROOT = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project/static"
```

2)the nginx configure file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {

    server {
           listen       800  default_server;
           server_name  mysite.com;
           return       444;
           location /static/ {
                  alias /dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project/static;
                            }
           }
```

3) the default file in /etc/nginx/sites-availables :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root  /dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I expect the static files to show up

=============================
EDIT:

The error message I get when I try to open the static file is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested resource was not found on this server.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` (which will copy all your static files into /dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project)?

Comment: yes, and checked for the existence of the files

Comment: check the nginx logs. maybe permission issues.

Comment: in `/etc/nginx/sites-availables` change `root  /dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project/static;` to `alias  /dir1/dir2/dir3/django_project/static;`

Comment: you can see a complete nginx conf for django [here](https://gist.github.com/katoozi/3f848b0b37b09edd541eeba3a28724b4) and [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/katoozi/9d7794cb4b419a0814578df393673ed6)

Comment: @katoozi I changed it and only the homepage can see the static files now it doesn't work for the rest of the pages in the site

Comment: remove `server` block config from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site works now.

The problems were many but all related to either nginx or gunicorn settings.

Always check for nginx and gunicorn errors:

Troubleshooting Nginx and Gunicorn discussed in details here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04